# configuring PHP and CodeIgniter to use an Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

Hi All
i'm trying to configure PHP and CodeIgniter to use an Oracle database instead of using mysql 5.3.3.
It will be great if anybody can give me step by step solution to do this
note that i installed oracle database 10g express edition,but when i try to import .sql i get an error that tell me that this file is not supported
Thank You

Comment: Codeigniter is not designed to support oracle 'out of the box'.  Is there a reason you can't use a supported DB ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,in our i create a small program  and it must work in all databes types(mysql,MSSQL, and oracle),for this reason i should configure my program to use oracle database

Answer (score 2):

You cannot import a MySQL database definition into an oracle database. While both speak SQL the table definitions are pretty different (especially regarding auto_increment/serial fields and varchar fields).

You **might** be able to create the empty tables in your oracle database if Codeigniter supports orable at all and then import your data (only the data) into that database.